# Spring NoClassDefFoundError: wrong name

Tags: java, spring, servlets, gradle

I have the following class:

```
package com.spring.domain;

@Document(collection = "sportactions") // for my mongodb collection
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class SportAction extends Action {
      //code logic
}
```

When I compile it, it gives me the following error:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
>   [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/spring/domain/**Sportaction** (wrong
>   name: com/spring/domain/**SportAction**)] with root cause 
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/spring/domain/**Sportaction** (wrong
>   name: com/spring/domain/**SportAction**)

I was confused as I can see my class is called SportAction with a capital `A` and not a small letter `a` so then I attempted to refactor my class name to see if it will work with a small letter `a`.

I got the following error:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
>   [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/spring/domain/**SportAction** (wrong
>   name: com/spring/domain/**Sportaction**)] with root cause 
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/spring/domain/**SportAction** (wrong
>   name: com/spring/domain/**Sportaction**)

The spring application will compile perfectly but this will appear at run time when I try to use the class.

I also did several `clean` and then `build` on gradle and it still doesn't work.

Does anyone know what is wrong with the code?

The error arose in this line of my java code when I try to fetch a list of Sportaction from mongodb:

```
List<Sportaction> sportactions = mongoTemplate.find(query, Sportaction.class);
```

Comment: Does it happen when you do it from the IDE, command line or both?

Comment: I will try it later on the command line but the gradle build is successful and it just bombs out during run time. I should also let u know that im working on the code now on a mac and its fine. But when I push it to Windows, the error occurs.

Comment: I tried it on the command line and IDE to gradlew clean and then gradlew build and same error results.

Comment: Don't you have xml configuration that is missusing the name ?

Comment: No, I'm using spring boot so no xml config files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this error occurred, but my build.gradle file required me to build a jar like so:

```
task stage(type: Copy, dependsOn: [clean, build]) {
    from jar.archivePath
    into project.rootDir 
    rename {
        'app.jar'
    }
}
stage.mustRunAfter(clean)

clean << {
    project.file('app.jar').delete()
}
```

When I ran it and pushed it onto my repo, I got a very strange error where my filename was now SportAction but my class name inside my java file was:

```
public class Sportaction
```

This caused a mismatch, and I tried refactoring the name to match the filename `SportAction` but the same wrong name error arose. I then decided to refactor the name to something else like `SportEvents` and then rerun the code and then it worked.

This isn't the best solution but it will have to do for now. I suspect it has something to do with the way the jar was built but I'm not sure as the `app.jar` was never run. The `Application.main()` was the class that ran when I ran my Spring app.

I'm also confused as to why my SportAction class on bitbucket does not seem to have a commit at all - see those 3 dots next to my Action file - it doesn't have a date and neither does it have a description.

[image]